# Laravel Vite not loading css on mobile device

Tags: css, laravel

I have a strange problem with my vite...

I have a site in dev, and when I view it from PC, the laravel breeze tailwind css is perfectly loaded, there are no errors. But when I try the same from a mobil device, it says that it can't load neither the css nor the js, because connection refused.

How can it be, that it works on PC and not on mobile? My vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            './public/css/app.css',
            './public/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

My error message on mobile:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/css/app.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Same for app.js

Do I need to specify the prod IP somewhere? Or that it uses SSL? Or need to put the files to other dirs? Or what? On desktop it works perfectly, on mobile (and/or on windows tablet!) it does not at all.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you resolve this issue ? My issue is like your's, in mobile device I have a total white page without any message and I use a responsive template build with vuejs 3 , tailwindcss and vitejs